# Invalid Parameter error in libcurl in c while curl_easy_perform(curl);

Tags: c, curl, runtime-error, libcurl

I am trying to make a post request to a server using libcurl. For Some data, the call is working but for some data, the call is throwing invalid parameter error in c. I checked all the codes of curl_easy_setopt() returning 1 and curl_easy_init() not null. I don't find anything wrong with the url or the data. It is saying stream!=nullptr.

Here is my code

```
CURL *curl;
            CURLcode res;
            curl = curl_easy_init();
            if (curl) {
                struct string s;
                //header 
                struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
                //  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "AUTHTOKEN: YxJNtWiQDo5do7XgQBFnq0gL50kEik1NEvGdCoGM922XF3vEU%2F3bynMQVn0nBLl2ryJcQ06tKCUk%0Atzhbm6vMJA%3D%3D");
                chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, authToken);
                chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk,pmptype);

                //error handling
                char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
                init_string(&s);
                //  char* url = "https://sabareesan-pt3029:7272/api/json/request?OPERATION_NAME=GET_PASSWORD";
                char* url = baseURL;
                // const char * inputData = "INPUT_DATA={\"operation\":{\"Details\":{\"PASSWDID\":\"49311\",\"REASON\":\"sdfgh\",\"TICKETID\":\"\"}}}";
                 //const char * inputData = "";
                printf("%d",curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, inputData));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errbuf));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writefunc));
                printf("%d", curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s));
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                if (res != CURLE_OK) {
                    size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
                    fprintf(f, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", res);
                    if (len)
                        fprintf(f, "%s%s", errbuf,
                        ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
                    else
                        fprintf(f, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
                    MessageBox(NULL, errbuf, "Connection Error",
                        MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                }
                else
                {
                       //response handling
                }
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this? Anyone know what i am missing in it or how to solve it?

Comment: Try to do `curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL)` before `curl_easy_init()`

Comment: @stderr IIRC `curl_easy_init` calls `curl_global_init` under the hood if it is not done already by the user, although this is a discouraged practice

Comment: @joH1 I know, I know... I've had this problem before on the windows platform using HTTPS, and if I remember correctly this made it work.

Comment: "invalid parameter error" ? is that a compiler error really? It sounds like something you actually get back in the response from the server...

Comment: @joH1 May i know which one is the discourage practice? Directly calling curl_easy_init() without curl_global_init()?

Comment: @DanielStenberg The error is from the file pointer in writefunc. It is not the response. I solved it.

Comment: The error was in the code you didn't even show? Awesome...

Comment: @DanielStenberg sorry for the inconvenience actually. I am just started working with libcurl. I got the error when i am calling the curl_easy_perform() which internally called the writefunc() by itself. I thought there is something wrong with the curl_easy_perform();